# nodeport service seems to not be passing along request headers to the pod/container

Tags: kubernetes, curl, http-headers, bearer-token

I have a container/pod that exposes 2 ports, 3000, and 3010 as separate nodeport services. The exposed APIs on port 3010 work fine as those do not require an authorization header, however the services on port 3000 DO require a bearer authorization
token header and it seems somehow it's getting stripped or something?

Any request I send I get back a 401 unauthorized. I'm testing locally with minikube in Mac OS X. I am using the `minikube service <servicename> --url` command to get the URL for the nodeport service and then proceeding to run `curl` on the provided URL to test connectivity.

```
curl --location --request GET http://<url>:<port>/info/ping --header 'Authorization: Bearer blah'
```

returns:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

This is despite the fact that `blah` is the bearer auth token.

Is this known issue? What possibly else could be going on? I have replicated this with a different container that also uses bearer auth.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In theory nothing should be stripped.

NodePorts are layer 4 ports TCP/UDP and http is layer 7.  I would take a look at your Bearer token if it has a newline or some other character at the end.

I would also debug in the pod itself:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash
# curl localhost:<local-service-pod> ...
```